# Prevent Cast Between Two Interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, interface, polymorphism, implementation

I have an internal class which contains implementation details, including properties, which should not be publicly accessible.  I have to pass this class to public callers, and allow them to pass it around, store it, serialize it, or do basically whatever they want with it.  The class can be accessed publicly in two different ways.  These ways are exposed as two public interfaces.  I would like to prevent the user from casting between the two public interfaces.  Here is some code to demonstrate what I am talking about.

```
void Main()
{
    var container = new ContainsDetails(5);

    Console.WriteLine(container.LessDetail.TheDetails);
    var more = (ContainsDetails.IFooPlus)(container.LessDetail);
    more.TheDetails = 10;
    Console.WriteLine(container.LessDetail.TheDetails);
}

public class ContainsDetails {
    public interface IFooPlus {
        int TheDetails {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public interface IFoo {
        int TheDetails {
            get;
        }
    }

    private readonly Detail _myDetail;

    public ContainsDetails(int x) {
        _myDetail = new Detail(x);
    }

    public IFoo LessDetail {
        get {
            return _myDetail;
        }
    }

    public IFooPlus MoreDetail {
        get {
            return _myDetail;
        }
    }

    public bool ProcessFoo(IFoo foo) {
        var theDeets = foo as Detail;
        if (theDeets != null) {
            return theDeets.TheDetails++%2 == 0;
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException("foo argument must have originated from ContainsDetails.");
        }
    }

    private class Detail : IFooPlus, IFoo {
        private int _myX;

        private Detail() {}

        internal Detail(int x) {
            _myX = x;
        }

        public int TheDetails {
            get {return  _myX; }
            set { _myX = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
5
10
```

I would like for the output above to be:

```
5
System.InvalidCastException thrown.....
```

The class `ContainsDetails` is just present for demonstration.  In my actual code the assembly fills the role of `ContainsDetails`. Similarly, `Detail` is an `internal` class in my actual code.

Here the user knows about both `IFooPlus` and `IFoo`.  The user does not know that `Detail` exists.  The user also does not know that the object returned by `LessDetail` is convertible to an `IFooPlus`.  My code returns the same `Detail` object to the user at different times, and will return it as `IFoo` or `IFooPlus` depending on some complicated state of `Detail` and other internal objects.  Also note the `ProcessFoo` method in `ContainsDetails`.  My code needs to be able to accept an `IFoo` from the user, and process it as a `Detail`.

I would like for the cast `var more = (ContainsDetails.IFooPlus)(container.LessDetail)` to generate an `InvalidCastException`.  It is prohibitively expensive to do runtime checking on all `IFooPlus` operations to determine if the `Detail` object is in the correct state for those operations.  Instead I would like the user never to be able to treat an `IFoo` as an `IFooPlus`.

The only option I can think of is to embed some `IFoo` member subclass inside of `Detail` and have the `Detail` and the subclass hold references to each other.  Yuck.

Is there a best practice for preventing this sort of casting, or should I just enclose the `IFoo` functionality in a member subclass of `Detail`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is to have a read-only wrapper which has a reference to the writable one. So `LessDetail` would always return the same wrapper reference, but `MoreDetail` would return a reference to the "real" type. You can then make both of them implement an *internal* interface which allows you to do whatever you need to, with the wrapper probably proxying those calls to the underlying object.

Alternatively, you could try to revisit your design - it doesn't sound ideal at the moment, either in terms of not being able to cast between the types or that `ProcessFoo` *accepts* any `IFoo` at compile-time, but is *really* only able to handle one particular implementation. This feels like an abuse of inheritance to me.

Comment: In fact IFoo is IAsyncResult, and ProcessFoo is BeginReadxxx, EndRead, BeginWritexxx, etc.  I can't accept anything more restrictive than IFoo (IAsyncResult) because my code needs to conform to the old Async pattern.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk: That's ugly but at least a *reasonable* explanation. This is why it's worth providing context in the question...

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that there would be some creative way to override the casting operators to just throw an exception.  `IFoo` and `IFooPlus` are tightly coupled with thread synchronization code. I have to be careful not to alter state while inside the user's callback :).  If such a cast override doesn't exist I will just try use a readonly wrapper class.  Thanks!