# Disable casting to explicit runtime type

Tags: c#, casting

I want to pass objects as an interface type, and disable the option to cast the object to its runtime type. Thus only allowing the methods that are declared in the interface, when the object is passed to other entities.

Motivation for this at the end.

My example with farther explanations:

```
class Program
{
    private interface Interface1
    {
        public void InterfaceAction();
    }

    private class Class1 : Interface1
    {
        public void InterfaceAction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Interface action");
        }

        public void ClassAction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class action");
        }
    }

    private class Class2
    {
        public void UseTheInterface(Interface1 interfaceObject)
        {
            // At the context of Class2 execution, from the signature of the method I only know that 
            //      received object is of Interface1, thus I can only use its method "InterfaceAction"
            interfaceObject.InterfaceAction();

            // As the runtime type of "interfaceObject" is Class1, I can cast to it
            Class1 casted = (Class1) interfaceObject;

            // Now after I revealed the object real type, I can use its unique method "ClassAction"
            casted.ClassAction();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
        Class2 obj2 = new Class2();

        // Here an auto cast to Interface1 is made on obj1
        obj2.UseTheInterface(obj1);

        // Actual output:
        //      Interface action
        //      Class action

        // Wanted output:
        //      Interface action
        //      Cast exception at line 35
    }
}
```

I know that in general, the cast shouldn't fail as it is actually the runtime type of the object.
However, I want to implement a safe way to use objects when passing them from one class to another.

Let's say I want to pass an object to some class and reveal only part of its methods by using an interface, as shown above. I don't want to rely on the other class to make proper usage out of it and use the interface methods alone, I want to make sure it can't access any other methods besides those in the interface.

Assuming the other class accepts the interface as a parameter for the function, it only knows its declared type and thus shouldn't try to cast. However, the other class can simply try brute force casting to each and every one of "Interface1" implementors, until it finds the appropriate type.
Also it would be possible to get the runtime type by using .GetType() extension method, then cast using a switch condition, without brute forcing.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You should make the implementation of the interface `internal` so the type can not be used outside the implementing assembly. Also going the reflection way and using the `GetType()` starting point can not be prevented.

Comment: I do want to use this type outside the assemly. I just don't want whoever gets Interface1 to be able to cast it to Class1, in case the runtime type is actually Class1.

Comment: There is no to prevent that, if you do not want a wrapper like mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a situation where you might use a wrapper.  The wrapper would implement the interface and would have an internal reference to the actual object that it would call in its implementation.  Then casting the interface would only ever get you the wrapper.

Example

```
class Program
{
    private interface Interface1
    {
        void InterfaceAction();
    }

    private class Class1ToInterface1 : Interface1
    {
        Class1 wrapped;
        public Class1ToInterface1(Class1 wrapped)
        {
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        public void InterfaceAction()
        {
            wrapped.InterfaceAction();
        }
    }

    private class Class1 : Interface1
    {
        public void InterfaceAction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Interface action");
        }

        public void ClassAction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class action");
        }
    }

    private class Class2
    {
        public void UseTheInterface(Interface1 interfaceObject)
        {
            // At the context of Class2 execution, from the signature of the method I only know that 
            //      received object is of Interface1, thus I can only use its method "InterfaceAction"
            interfaceObject.InterfaceAction();

            // As the runtime type of "interfaceObject" is Class1, I can cast to it
            Class1 casted = (Class1)interfaceObject; // InvalidCastException

            // Now after I revealed the object real type, I can use its unique method "ClassAction"
            casted.ClassAction(); // Won't get this far
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 obj1 = new Class1();
        Class2 obj2 = new Class2();
        Interface1 interfaceToObj1 = new Class1ToInterface1(obj1);

        // Here an auto cast to Interface1 is made on obj1
        obj2.UseTheInterface(interfaceToObj1);

        // Actual output:
        //      Interface action
        //      Class action

        // Wanted output:
        //      Interface action
        //      Cast exception at line 35
    }
}
```

This should generate a `System.InvalidCastException` "Unable to cast object of type 'Class1ToInterface1' to type 'Class1'." on the line line:

```
Class1 casted = (Class1)interfaceObject; // InvalidCastException
```

Comment: Your answer is basically to use an adapter. However, I don't want to change the runtime type that is being used, just to prevent being able to cast to it.

Comment: @OhadVano Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389900/prevent-cast-between-two-interfaces